# Does Terraria have controller compatibility?

Tags: terraria, controllers

I have Terraria via Steam and I usually play with a keyboard and mouse. I'd like to play with my Xbox controller but I can't find a joystick option. So can you use a controller for PC Terraria?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just busted a brief google search to find that they plan to add controller support in version 1.3.1, the release date is TBA at this stage.

References:

- [Terraria Forums](http://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/pc-is-getting-controller-support.39954/)
- [Terraria Gamepedia](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Upcoming_features#Terraria_1.3.1)

however if you not willing to wait there are several game profilers available for use such as:

- [Pinnical](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjswPG8qd3MAhUJtJQKHSMJD6oQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpinnaclegameprofiler.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNEL8ggVz9_Fb_02kQCONpoP9TDqow&sig2=gHrpaVN0HfyuhAxQWaXXuQ&bvm=bv.122129774,d.dGo)
- [Input mapper](https://inputmapper.com/)

or finally a forum post from [Terraria online](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/gamepad-control-xbox360-etc.61766/) that describes a process for allowing game-pads (xbox360, gamecube, ps3 and Wii Classic ) to work.